# (Android) Making Images Visible/Not Visible when touched

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

This is my updated code.  It doesn't detect movement at all now.  Maybe I shouldn't be making each Image an instance?  Basically I want to user to be able to swipe through all the images to make them dissapear.

Thanks for all the help.

```
package com.picomputing.mythirdapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Paul on 8/13/13.
 */
public class Pin extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    boolean isPinDown;

    public Pin(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.isPinDown = false;
    }

    public Pin(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isPinDown = false;
    }

    public Pin(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.isPinDown = false;
    }

    public boolean pinDown() {
        return this.isPinDown;
    }

    public void setPinDown() {
        this.isPinDown = true;
    }

    public void setPinUp() {
        this.isPinDown = false;
    }

    public void togglePin() {
        if (isPinDown == false)
        {
            isPinDown = true;
            this.setImageResource(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            isPinDown = false;
            this.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x = (int) event.getX();  //--relative to mLayout--
                int y = (int) event.getY();  //--relative to mLayout--
                Rect r = new Rect();
                view.getHitRect(r);
                    if(r.contains(x,y) && view instanceof ImageView){
                        togglePin();
                    }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want to prevent the user to touch multiple images?

Comment: No, I would like them to touch multiple images.  But I don't want them to have to pick up their finger to make each image invisible.  I want them to be able to swipe through all of them.

Comment: Is the code above giving the behaviour you describe? As written it looks like your buttons should be toggling like crazy as each Pin that is currently being touched receives dozens of touch events per second and each one toggles the view.

Comment: No, it only toggles the original image that was touched.  The other images don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen and consume `ACTION_MOVE` events, for the parent view of whatever you are trying to change.

Here's an example with a couple of `ImageView`s in a `LinerLayout` as a parent:

```
public class test extends Activity {
    LinearLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            mLayout.addView(iv);
        }


        setContentView(mLayout);

        mLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x = (int) event.getX();  //--relative to mLayout--
                        int y = (int) event.getY();  //--relative to mLayout--
                        Rect  r = new Rect();
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < mLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                            View v = mLayout.getChildAt(i);
                            v.getHitRect(r);
                            if(r.contains(x,y) && v instanceof ImageView){
                                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            }
                        }

                }
                return true; //-- this means that view is interested in more events of all kinds--
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I want to have each image be it's own instance.

Comment: @user2684766 This is an example showing the basics of finding whether touch is moving over a view or not. You are free to use your own view setups.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your question
but if what you want to do is to prevent multitoch on the image you can add this attribute

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

in the xml in the parent view of the imageview. for example :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" 
    >
 // YOUR IMAGE VIEW HERE
</LinearLayout>
```

if you have any question feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase my question the best.  Right now if the user moves his finger through all the images, only the first one will toggle to make it not visible.  I would like them to be able to make them all invisible in one motion.

Comment: I have ten of these images on the screen specified in my layout file.  Basically I want the user to be able to slice through them (like Fruit Ninja if you have ever played that game)

Answer (score 0):

there are mainly three events on OnTouch action_down,Action_move and Action_up. do your coding on action down event i.e when user has touched your view. see the example here:

```
     @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            //write your code here
        }
        else {
            if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                do things

            }
            else {
                if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    do things
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  The problem is, I have used the Action_Down event, and it will detect when the user touches the first image, but will not detect on the following images until the user picks his finger back up and touches it.